# Problem with Validations in Angular. Checkbox with email input

Tags: angular, typescript

I don't know what the problem is. Still, when I run on localhost, I see a warning text that "email is required". It is based on the fact that when checkbox is selected, the e-mail input should be required but when is not = not.

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup,FormControl,FormBuilder,Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {forbiddenNameValidator} from './shared/name.validator';
import {PasswordValidator} from './shared/password.validator';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    get userName() {
        return this.registrationForm.get('userName');
    }
    get passPro() {
        return this.registrationForm.get('password');
    }
    get conPro() {
        return this.registrationForm.get('confirmPassword');
    }
    get email() {
        return this.registrationForm.get('email');
    }

    registrationForm: FormGroup;
    //adress: FormGroup;
    //Sposób 2 bardziej spakowany

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({
            userName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(512), forbiddenNameValidator(/password/)]],
            password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(512)]],
            confirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(512)]],
            adress: this.fb.group({
                name: [''],
                surname: [''],
                email: [''],
                dateB: [''],
                adres: [''],
                city: [''],
                postalCode: [''],
                subscribe: [false]
            })
        }, {
            validator: PassworrdValidator
        });

        this.registrationForm.get('subscribe').valueChanges
            .subscribe(checkedValue => {
                const email = this.registrationForm.get('email');
                if (checkedValue) {
                    email.setValidators(Validators.required);
                } else {
                    email.clearValidators();
                }
                email.updateValueAndValidity();
            });

    }
}
```

Part of **app.component.html** - only from adress:this.fb group

```
<h2>Dane użytkownika</h2>
<div formGroupName="adress">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input formControlName="name" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Surname</label>
        <input formControlName="surname" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Birthdate</label>
        <input formControlName="dateB" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Adres</label>
        <input formControlName="adres" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Postal Code</label>
        <input formControlName="postalCode" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>City</label>
        <input formControlName="city" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email adress</label>
        <input [class.is-invalid]="email.invalid && email.touched" formControlName="email" type="text"
            class="form-control">
        <small class="text-danger" [class.d-none]="email.valid || email.untouched">Email is required</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check mb-3">
        <input class="form-control-check" formControlName="subscribe" type="checkbox">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            Send me promotional offers.
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check mb-3">
        <input class="form-control-check" formControlName="subscribe" type="checkbox">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            I accept the terms and conditions.
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

1. TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of null
2. property 'valueChanges' of null at AppComponent.ngOnInit
3. and CONTEX errors
4. Why it appears ? Omg why enter doesnt work here..

Comment: your "subscribe" and "email" is in the formGroup "adress", so, you must use  `this.registrationForm.get('adress').get('subscribe')` and `this.registrationForm.get('adress').get('email')`

Comment: Jezus that was so easy...O M G ...God bless u man ^^

Comment: or simply `this.registrationForm.get('adress.subscribe')`